# Paragraph width as big/small as text

Tags: html, css

I want to create a paragraph element with variable text.
and I want that element as big as the text inside, so i can make a border around it.

The Border the should only go around the text and not over the whole side.
The word inside the paragraph element should also be variable (different length).

Thanks for your help.

```css
p {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hello
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display (inline-block)

```css
p {
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>
  hello
</p>
```